# How can I start Algebraic K-Theory?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can you please tell me what are pr-requisite area to learn Algebraic K-Theory ? I studied Linear Algebra , Rings and Modules ,Fields and Galois Theory ,basic Commutative Algebra , Calculus on Differential Forms, Algebraic Topology without Co-homology .Now I am studying Topological Graph Theory but I cant find the interest on it . I want to learn Algebraic K-Theory from basic level . Please suggest me the books so that I can learn and able to do research in future on it .

Comment: Well damn, you started me on it because this is the first time I've ever heard of it

Answer (score 3):

You should just try to start reading the [K-book](https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eweibel/Kbook.html)! It sounds like you have enough background to get started.